# MPI. Проблемы с алгоритмом

Tags: c++, алгоритм, матрицы, mpi

Норма находится как максимальная по модулю сумма элементов строки. Вроде что-то распараллелил, процессы подсчитывают суммы, но в цикл нахождения максимума заходит только один процесс. Да и как сделать так, чтобы программа работала при условии, что кол-во процессов меньше элементов матрицы, то есть одному процессу придется работать с несколькими итерациями?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include<stdio.h>
#include "conio.h"
#include <mpi.h>
const int N=10;
 int max,sum,t;
 int a[N][N],b[N];//задаем массив
 int proc_count, proc_this, quant, ibeg;

int main(int argc,char** argv)
{

sum=0;    
max=0; 
    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
           a[i][j]=rand()%20;
        }//заполняем массив
    }
MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&proc_count);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&proc_this);
t = MPI_Wtime();

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
    if (proc_this == i) //каждый процесс делает одну итерацию
    {
            for ( int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                    sum += abs( a[ i ][ j ] );
            } 
            b[i] = sum; 
    }
        sum = 0; 
    }

    if (proc_this == 0)   
    {
    max=b[0];
        for ( int k=1; k < N; k++ ) 
    {
        if ( b[ k ] > max ) 
        {
                    max = b[ k ];
            }
        }
    printf("norma=%d",max);
    printf("time=%f", MPI_Wtime()-t);  
    }

MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Comment: @noidea, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы процесс мог выполнять более одной итерации, сравнение можно по модулю `proc_count` производить, предполагая, что `0 <= proc_this < proc_count`.

Цикл с максимумом также должен использовать `if (proc_this == k % proc_count)`. А затем вызывать `MPI_Reduce()`, чтобы глобальный максимум найти. Процессы работают с локальными копиями данных, если их явно не передать.